# Learnt something at or learnt something in?

Tags: prepositions

If I say, I learnt something at 11th grade, is that correct? Or at should be used only when referring to places or particular dates?

Answer (score 1):

*"At"* here is incorrect. *"I learnt something in 11th grade"* is correct.

We use at, in, and on fairly arbitrarily depending on what we're referring to. The correct preposition here is *in*